# More than 8 lights without deferred shading / lighting

Tags: opengl, glsl

I want to know if there is any technique (efficient) to use more than 8 lights in a scene made ​​with OpenGL and GLSL. Without making use of deferred shading / lighting.

I have not implementadon these techniques for their limitations and not being able to use transparency or antialiasing.

If there is a good alternative, describe it with an example.

I use OpenGL 2.0.

Thank you.

Comment: How are you doing your lighting now? What kind of lighting are you using? How did you reach the concluion that 8 is the maximum amount of lights possible?

Comment: Also, what are you trying to do? I find it hard to imagine a type of game in which you actually need more than 8 lights (per pixel, I suppose?).

Comment: Well basically try to remove the limitation of 8 lights. I would make a scene for example where there is at least 30 lights. but efficiently

Comment: -what- limitation of 8 lights? What kind of lights? There's a million different types of lights you can use, each with different requirements on your shaders, and there's a million different types of devices and drivers which impose different restrictions on your code. Are you sure you know what a light is (in GLSL terms)? are you sure you're using OpenGL 2.0?

Comment: Also, please do not [crosspost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24481434) on different stackexchange sites. View the discussion on crossposting [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/)

Comment: He's talking about the old fixed-functionality OpenGL. It have GL_LIGHT_* definitions that only went up to 8. Of course there's no limit to lights, but he's limited by the old OpenGL interface.

Comment: He is talking about GLSL so he is not limited to the fixed function pipeline. When you can not do more than 8 lights in one pass you have to do another pass. Simply render the object again additivly with the additional lights. Repeat until done. If that is too slow you will need Deferred Shading or some other buffering technique or you have to cull your lights more efficiently.

Comment: I really hate this about stack* sites: a perfectly good and useful question is hammered to the ground for silly reasons. +1

Answer (score 2):

the limitation you're finding is somewhat related to the history of OpenGL. Prior to OpenGL 3, a fixed-function pipeline was employed. This roughly means than OpenGL would execute the exact same processing on all vertices. The only way you could modify the output was by changing the input arguments of the pipeline (vertex positions, colors, light properties, ... ). This means the OpenGL API contained a lot of functions to change these input parameters. In specific, to set the properties of lights, the OpenGL provides 8 different lights to change the properties of.

In modern OpenGL, the fixed-function pipeline was replaced by the programmable pipeline. This roughly means that you can program the pipeline to perform any kind of processing of the vertices. You can use widely different processing for different textures/materials you're trying to emulate. These programs are programmed as "shaders". The "negative" side of this, is that no functionality is provided for you. You start of with an empty pipeline and need to write it from scratch. The minimum you need is atleast a vertex shader and a fragment shader. The advantage is, that you can program the pipeline to your liking. You could for example pass an array of 20 lights (rather than the default of 8 lights in fixed-function pipeline OpenGL). So, a solution would be to switch to a more modern version of OpenGL.

However! In most cases you won't need more than 8 lights. Lighting is fairly complex to calculate. If you want excellent looking lights, you'll likely use per-pixel lighting (phong shading) in the vertex shader. For every additional light, you need additional calculations per pixel. The more lights, the more processing time, meaning you'll notice slowdown.

The solution is clever disabling of lights. In modern games, only a few light are active at a time. Lights are disabled and re-enabled based on camera position, occlusion and more. Consider for example point lights. The intensity of the light reflecting of your objects lowers the further away the light is. This is called distance attenuation. At a certain distance, you will not notice the influence of the light anymore. It is thus safe to disable the light, freeing up a lot of processing time (calculations are done for every single fragment!) without visual impact. Another solution is to approximate multiple light sources by a single source. For example, consider having a swarm of 100 fireflies swooping across your game map. You can safely approximate these 100 light sources by a single source in the center of the swarm. The summed contribution of the 100 individual lights will be almost indistinguishable from a single-source approximation.

In summary: if you really want more than 8 lights, take a look at modern OpenGL (OpenGL 3+) and write your shaders to accomodate this. However, more than 8 lights are almost never required. Consider enabling and disabling lights (eg. enable only the 8 closest lights to the player/camera in every frame). Try to approximate multiple close lights sources by single sources.

As you already know about GLSL, you might find modern OpenGL very interesting. While it's more difficult to write the entire shader pipeline from scratch, you'll be happy once you're fluent in it as it offers you a lot of power in graphics processing!